# 100% I/O utilization when mysqlcheck is running

Tags: mysql, performance

The following mysqlcheck commands (run daily) are causing 100% Disk I/O utilization for a long period of time (1-2 hours):

```bash
mysqlcheck --check --auto-repair --all-databases; 
mysqlcheck --optimize --all-databases
```

Which mysql server configuration settings can be used in order to prevent/limit high disk I/O?

posted the entire mysql configuration here: https://pastebin.com/huvkfkUF .
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why in the world are you running this daily? This type of command is *going* to consume all the I/O it can. You could look at `ionice`, but even that may not be sufficient.

Comment: Regarding daily: is there any universally acceptable time intervals for running these commands?
Regarding ionice: should i limit mysql server using ionice?

Comment: Run it when you see evidence of needing to run it.

Comment: @EEAA ok, i thought there is a proactive and automatic solution for keeping mysql tables optimized at all times. Thanks in any way!

Comment: Think of it like brushing your teeth.  All day long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Universally acceptable time interval ..." -- "never".  Seriously, change your app tables from MyISAM to InnoDB, and you won't need to ever run `mysqlcheck` again.

Also, set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of RAM, not the paultry 128MB.

How much RAM do you have?

Comment: The config already has `default_storage_engine  InnoDB` ... so maybe tables are already mostly InnoDB.

Comment: Perhaps MyISAM tables were imported or held over from an upgrade?